# Connect to Oracle DB instance using R

Tags: r, oracle, odbc

I try to connect to an oracle DB using Rstudio, but I can't figure out how to do it. I have connected to the database with PowerBi, so I know it is accessible (from my pc/ip) and that the database works fine, however using R I cannot get this done. Prior to asking this question I have been searching the web for days, I'm not new to R or SQL, but I am to Oracle. I have tried various packages (DBI, odbc, RODBC etc.) but still no success.
I have talked to the administrators of the DB, they said I should be able to connect using the following information which is provided to me;

Server: xxx.xxx.xx.xx

Port : xxxx

Instance : ORCL

User: *myusername*

Pwd : *mypwd*

When I connect to the DB using PowerBI, my server name is: server/instance, in combination with the uid and pwd the connection than works fine.

The closest I (think I) got, was using the 'odbcDriverConnect()' function.
First I ran the following command to check which drivers are installed;

`sort(unique(odbcListDrivers()[[1]]))`

which gave as output

`"Oracle in OraClient12Home1" "Oracle in OraClient12Home2" "SQL Server"`

Other topics here on stackoverflow, suggested the following site to check which string to use in the function:

https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

I couldn't find a specific one for my listed drivers, but I altered the one for the *Oracle in OraClient11g_home1* since it seemed to be the best match, this string is as follows;

Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};Server=serverSID;Uid=myUsername; Pwd=myPassword;

So I replaced the *Oracle in OraClient11g_home1* with my drivers, they all gave another error;

```
con <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home1};Server=xxx.xxx.xx.xx/orcl;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;")


Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home1};Server=xxx.xxx.xx.xx/orcl;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM003, code 160, message Het opgegeven stuurprogramma kan niet worden geladen vanwege een systeemfout  126: Kan opgegeven module niet vinden. (Oracle in OraClient12Home1, C:\Program Files\Oracle\product\12.2.0\client_1\SQORA32.DLL).
2: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home1};Server=xxx.xxx.xx.xx/orcl;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;") :
  ODBC connection failed
```

The error is in Dutch, stating that the driver cannot be found due to systemerror 126

the next driver gives another error;

```
con <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home2};Server=xxx.xxx.xx.xx/orcl;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;")

Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home2};Server=xxx.xxx.xx.xx/orcl;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code 12560, message [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
2: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home2};Server=xxx.xxx.xx.xx/orcl;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;") :
  ODBC connection failed
```

The last driver, is the only one who takes a few seconds, suggesting its actually trying to connect, but eventually also gives an (other) error;

```
con <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=xxx.xxx.xx.xx/orcl;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;")

Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=xxx.xxx.xx.xx/orcl;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 17, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]De SQL-server bestaat niet of de toegang tot de server is geweigerd.
2: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=xxx.xxx.xx.xx/orcl;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 53, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).
3: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=xxx.xxx.xx.xx/orcl;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;") :
```

Stating that the server doesn't exists or that the acces is denied. Once again, I know it exists and that  I am granted access because it works on powerBi, so I am kind off lost right now. I have tried the server with and without the */orcl*. If anyone has any clue on what I am missing that would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards

Comment: What is your environment ?.Did you install Oracle ODBC drivers 64 bit?

Comment: Yes, both windows and R run in 64 bit. Someone just commented here, his answer is deleted, I dont know why, but I think he gave me the solution. I tried;

odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home2};Dbq= myServerIP:myPort/orcl;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;")

I now got no errors and see a value for 'con' in environment with value 'RODBC int 1'

still not sure on how to go forward, but it seems (I think) I have established a connection

Comment: Yes that was me.I deleted that answer because I was not sure of your environment.Did you get the message connection successful?.When you see that message copy and paste into console which will show you schemas in database

Comment: I did not get that message, only an object in my environment as described in my previous comment, when I coppy the object (con) in my console I get this, not sure what it is, the tables I expect are named diffrently but they could be underllying or something (?)
RODBC Connection 1
Details:
  case=nochange
  DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient12Home2}
  SERVER=xxx.xxx.xx.xx:1521/orcl
  UID=***
  PWD=******
  DBQ=xxx.xxx.xx.xx:1521/orcl
  DBA=W
  APA=T
  EXC=F
  XSM=Default
  FEN=T
  QTO=T
  FRC=10
  FDL=10
  LOB=T
  RST=T
  BTD=F
  BNF=F
  BAM=IfAllSuccessful
  NUM=NLS
  DPM=F

Comment: the list goes on a little more, too much chars to print here

Comment: Oh and to answer your initial question, yes I work in R studio :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With instant client and ipaddress of server

```
con <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home2};Dbq=server_ipaddress:1521/orcl;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;")
```

or if you can ping server

```
 con <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home2};Dbq=server:1521/orcl;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;")
```

Other option if you have tnsnames.ora in instant client home and set tns_admin variable you can use service name in tnsnames.ora file

```
con <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home2};Dbq=orcl;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;")
```

[image]

P.S:-I never worked on R just downloaded R and R studio

Comment: Thanks allot man you really made my day, after establishing it in de 'connections' sections I got everything I needed :)

Comment: You're welcome I was about to post another screen shot for connections tab.Glad it worked out in the end.